# Python's virtualenv and directories

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I started a virtualenv session, and inside a directory `dir`, I have the following directory hierarchy:

```
| venv -- the virtual environment
| app_dir
  main.py
  | dir1
  | dir2
  | dir2
```

I've installed flask for this environment, which main.py uses. When I run `$ python main.py`, it will run through flask. My question here is - does `app_dir` and `venv` have to be sibling directories? Or can I have `app_dir` somewhere else? If so, how does `main.py` recognise `flask` to be in `venv`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be extra thorough, this is what you need to do to get your virtualenv working. After you install your virtualenv you just need to source it so that your current shell uses the virtualenv

In order to source the virtualenv you'd do this:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

So, as long as you source the correct virtualenv. Your `app_dir` and `venv` directories could be anywhere on your system.

Comment: in addition, you might want to check out [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper)

Comment: shameless plug, but you may also want to checkout [virtstrap](https://github.com/ravenac95/virtstrap) :-). It's software i wrote to manage repeatable virtualenvs. We've been using it at work for a while now. Although, there is still some work to make it better for prime time. :-)

Comment: So anything installed during the `virtualenv` session, will be part of that environment, and only be used when that environment is activated?

Comment: @Darksky yes, that's the case.

Comment: @Darksky, Yes. That is correct. To get out of the virtualenv "session" just type ``deactivate`` and you are back to the global python.